# Determine actual screen size (not by pixels)

Tags: size, screen, highdpi

everybody seems to use pixels to determine screen size of a device, but it is not a good practice anymore. You can use bootstrap to create a responsive website, but it will fail on full hd screens, because a lot of pixels, don't mean big screen anymore.

My example:
on bigger screens, I don't want website to take the entire screen and on smaller screens I do. The easy solution is to use max-width, but it doesn't work if a device has a full hd screen, because it's small with a lot of pixels.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 300dpi) {
    //styling which will be applied >= 300dpi
}
```

[Source 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#resolution)

[Source 2](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)